# Using the same baking paper as always, suddenly my bread sticks, what's happening?

Tags: baking, bread, parchment

I regularly bake bread (1+ times a week). I usually reuse a sheet of baking paper a few times, and for the last 20+ times it has been from the same roll. Now suddenly the last two breads I made are completely stuck to the (new sheet of) paper after baking. I have to cut off the bottom after slicing the bread.

What is happening? Some people told me certain brands of baking paper have two sides, one shiney (non-stick). Today I actually checked which side I was using and made sure to use the shiney side, but again it got completely stuck.
I thought the dough might be a bit too wet, but it wasn't *that* wet. Definitely not wetter than I've sometimes had in the past without problems.

Comment: Might be worth grabbing the box (so you can read any production codes off it) and calling the manufacturer - sounds like a potential quality control screw-up to me (i.e., you have baking paper which has not actually been treated in whatever way it should have been before it was packaged and sold.) Not, mind you, that I generally use baking paper (aka parchment) at all for bread.

Comment: Thanks, I did call the manufacturer who ended up sending me 2 new boxes, so that was great. I only realised later that my partner bought a refill for the box by a different brand. I felt sorry for blaming it on the original company as it turned out we just got a crappy replacement, and I didn't realise it..